# MSBUILD Executing only Changed SQL Scripts

Tags: msbuild

I need to construct an MSBUILD script executes .SQL Scripts which have changed since last build.

I initially thought that I could copy all scripts from one folder to another using the `<Copy>` task and using the CopiedFiles `<Output>` for the copy task. However the copy task returns All files that it Attempted to copy, not actual copied files.

I am able to get MSBUILD to execute SQL Scripts via MSBUILD.ExtensionPack but Im scratching my head on this one

Comment: it seems some of my text was interpreted as tags, Second paragraph should read:
I initially thought that I could copy all scripts from one folder to another using the COPY task and using the CopiedFiles OUTPUT for the copy task. However the copy task returns All files that it Attempted to copy, not actual copied files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a concept known as incremental building. The idea is that you would create a target and then specify the inputs and outputs, which would be files. MSBuild will compare the timestamps of the input files to the output files. If all outputs were created after all outputs then the target is skipped. If all inputs are newer then all the target will be executed for all files. If only a portion are out of date, then only those will be passed to the target. For more info on this see the section ***Using Incremental Builds*** in my article [Best Practices For Creating Reliable Builds, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx).

Also for more resources on MSBuild I have compiled a list at http://sedotech.com/Resources#MSBuild

Answer (score 3):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="RunScripts">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConnStr>Server=Example;Database=Example;Trusted_Connection=True</ConnStr>
    <BuildFolder>Build\</BuildFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Scripts Include="*.sql"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="RunScripts"
          Inputs="@(Scripts)"
          Outputs="@(Scripts->'$(BuildFolder)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <SqlExecute TaskAction="ExecuteScalar"
                Files="@(Scripts)"
                ConnectionString="$(ConnStr)"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Scripts)"
          DestinationFiles="@(Scripts->'$(BuildFolder)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: This is exatcly how to solve the issue also with Data Dude. It would be nice if MS will provide this task "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you copying into an empty destination?

**SkipUnchangedFiles**

```
If true, skips the copying of files that are unchanged 
between the source and destination. The Copy task considers 
files to be unchanged if they have the same size and the 
same last modified time.
```

In your case i suspect that all files are considered changed since they don't exist at the destination.

Comment: No, The copy task reports all attempted copied files not just actually copied files. This is an known issue I've seen while searching the interwebs.

Comment: @imbz - Dang it! You're right - i never heard about this stupid bug before.